# HtAccess: Basic ModRewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given urls like this:

```
mysite.com/index.php 
mysite.com/page/member/lobby.php 
mysite.com/page/videos/video1.php
```

How can I rewrite the urls with .htaccess to hide the /page/ folder when it's present?

So the end result is:

```
mysite.com/index.php
mysite.com/member/lobby.php
mysite.com/videos/video1.php
```

Comment: Why can you not place the files on disk in the right locations in the first place? This neatly circumvents your problem.

Comment: perhaps he has multiple directories that need to be consolidated and he just wants to understand the principle first.

Comment: Adrian you're correct on both counts, I originally structured my directories in the way I wanted them to display but then it became difficult to remember the name of each page folder and sift through other folders containing images,js,libraries,etc.  Consolidation is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to add `page/` to your path internally:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=page
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+ page/$0 [L]
```

Now every request that’s URI path has at least two path segments but that’s first segment is not `page` will be prefixes with `/page`. So `/member/lobby.php` will be rewritten to `/page/member/lobby.php`.